# Getting No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, cors, google-distancematrix-api

especificly i'm doing a get request to the distance matrix google api, but getting Getting No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.

```
this.http.get(googleApiurl).map(response => response.json()).subscribe(
    //Code here
);
```

Since this header is a response header and not request header, i'v tried:

```
In constructor->private res: ResponseOptions
this.res.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
```

Can you hep me?

Comment: Read about CORS. Basically your domain is not allowed to query the API. If this is an open API, there must be a way to add your domain to the list of whitelisted domains in the API configuration. Adding custom response headers won't work.

Comment: thanks @KabirRoy it's an ionic app, and i'm in testing enviroment, from localhost, the thing is: with angular code how i correctly set response headers for a get request, so the localhost domain could be accepted?

Comment: That's not related to Angular. The headers need to be sent from the server to the browser with the response.

Comment: thanks @GünterZöchbauer it's an public api, so...what can i do?

Comment: You can set up your own server that acts as a relay. CORS is only enforced by browsers, not by HTTP requests made from server code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to request Google APIs from your server. However if you don't want to setup a server there are some workarounds.

**Solution 1:**

I have faced the same issue and fixed it by using a PlacesService to get the PlaceID

```
// Get Place ID from Address 
function getPlaceIDFromAddress(address, callback){
          var place = {};
          var request = {
            location: new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLng),
            radius: '50',
            query: address
          };
          var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService($scope.mapContainer);
          service.textSearch(request, function(results, status){
             if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {     
                    var placeId = results[0].place_id;
                    var location = results[0].geometry.location;                    
                return callback(null, placeId);
              }
          });
    }
```

then pass the PlaceID to geocoder to get the LatLng or you can pass LatLng to GeoCode to get addresses.

```
(new google.maps.Geocoder()).geocode({placeId: places_id}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
     console.log("Address: ", results[0].formatted_address);
}});
```

**Solution 2:**

Not recommended though.

If you just want to test on your localhost you can install [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) chrome extension. Just turn it on before making a call to matrix api

This extension will insert the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in the header.